# SoundCloud “Artwork” player

Tags: html, soundcloud, artwork

We just recognised that the SoundCloud “Artwork” player which is accessible through the Pro Account is based on Flash - which is obviously a problem on OS X mobile devices.

http://blog.soundcloud.com/2011/11/03/html5/

Now the question is - is there a way to customize the standard HTML5 player to look similar to the Artwork player? Possibly just with CSS?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it's not possible to customise the HTML5 widget to look like artwork widget. You could build your own player with JavaScript that would work on iOS.